# Getting text from select option to modal bootstrap

Tags: php

How can I get the value from select option and pass it to a input in a bootstrap modal

```
     <select id="selected_category" name="selected_category" class="form-control"><br>
```

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_categories))
        {
        ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo($row['category_name'])?>" >
            <?php echo($row['category_name']) ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }               
    ?>
```

and here's my modal form.. I want to show it in the input type text category

```
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Add Item</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

 <form action="" method="post">
```

Selected Category:
 "name="category">

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value via JavaScript and add it client-side to the Bootstrap modal.

```
var element = document.getElementById("selected_category");
var selected= element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

You need to add an id to your input and then can access it via:

```
document.getElementById("Your Input-ID here").innerHTML = selected;
```